# Nuxt JS env file

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I'm using Nuxt JS 2.9.2, and am trying to use a `.env` file to load a unique encryption key, however, the following doesn't seem to pull the information from the env file, even after installing dotenv

```
 env: {
    encryption_key: process.env.ENCRYPTION_KEY || 'secret key 123'
  }
```

The above code is inserted inside of my `export default` inside of the nuxt config js file, it always seems to load the **secret key 123** rather than ENCRYPTION_KEY from the env file

Answer (score 4):

Here are the steps to get this working:

First install `dotenv` with `npm i -D dotenv`

Next, make sure you have a `.env` file that looks something like:

```
ENCRYPTION_KEY="put your key here"
```

Finally, add the following to the top of your `nuxt.config.js`:

```js
require('dotenv').config();
```

---

**A word of caution**

Please be aware that this will actually build your client code with `ENCRYPTION_KEY` in the source, so anyone could read it. If that isn't what you want, I'd recommend doing all of your encryption on the server.

Comment: I am looking into the same thing but through kubernetes. I am setting the environment variables in the job spec but doesnt take effect. Do we absolutely NEED the .env file in the source or is there a different way around it ?!

Comment: Also had a questions that the .env file or environment file should be available at build time or we can have it at runtime ?

Comment: See the dotenv docs about what to commit and when. You certainly don't want to add any of your secret keys to your source control system.